# как создать счётчик который будет считать количество сгенерированных строк, что б вывести их количество в консоль? c#

Tags: c#

```
        Console.Write("Введите минимум: ");
        int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите максимум: ");
        int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        min.ToString();
        int a1, a2;
        string s = "";
      
        for (; min < max; min++)
        {
            
            s = String.Format("{0:000000}", min);
            a1 = (int)s[0] + (int)s[1] + (int)s[2];
            a2 = (int)s[3] + (int)s[4] + (int)s[5];
            if (a1 == a2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
         
        }
```

Введите минимум: 100000
, Введите максимум: 101000 .

100001
100010
100100

Press any key to continue . . .

P.S мне нужно что бы вывело  количество сгенерированных строк " 3 " + какая была последняя "100100"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понял, в чем задача, но попробую в лоб.

```
Console.Write("Введите минимум: ");
int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Введите максимум: ");
int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string result = "";
int count = 0;
for (; min < max; min++)
{
    string s = String.Format("{0:000000}", min);
    int a1 = (int)s[0] + (int)s[1] + (int)s[2];
    int a2 = (int)s[3] + (int)s[4] + (int)s[5];
    if (a1 == a2)
    {
        result = s;
        count++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(count);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: да, что-то тоже не понял в чем проблема просто завести отдельную переменную и инкрементить её, если условие срабатывает 0_0